# parse error near `]' in git-prompt.sh when trying to update zshell prompt

Tags: git, macos, zsh

I'm trying to update my OSX (Monterey 12.1) zshell prompt to include the current Git branch and status.  I've copied the latest `git-prompt.sh` from GitHub ([this one](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5d01301f2b865aa8dba1654d3f447ce9d21db0b5/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh)) to `~/.git-prompt.sh`.

I have the following barebones file at `~/.zshrc` per the documentation:

```
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
setopt PROMPT_SUBST ; PS1='[%n@%m %c$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

When I start a terminal window, I get an error stating there's a "parse error near ']'" on line [318](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5d01301f2b865aa8dba1654d3f447ce9d21db0b5/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L318):

```
Last login: Tue Feb  1 14:06:54 on ttys000
/Users/<user>/.git-prompt.sh:318: parse error near `]'
zsh: command not found: __git_ps1                                                                                       
[<user>@<machine> ~]$
```

Am I somehow doing something incorrectly here? It looks like `git-prompt.sh` hasn't been changed in a while, so I *assume* it's stable.

Comment: Look at your `.git-prompt.sh` file, near line 318 (start at 318 and work your way further away, usually upwards, if necessary). From manual inspection of your link, I suspect you've expanded a literal tab into spaces; don't do that, or re-code the source to avoid the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's what happened.  Xcode apparently "helped" when I pasted the contents from GitHub into an empty file.  It changed _all_ the tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly speculated in the comments above, the version of `.git-prompt.sh` I was using had its tabs replaced with spaces (by my IDE), making parts of the script not get parsed as intended.  Copying it from the source into a different text editor that didn't change whitespace resulted in everything working correctly.